# Google+ statistics

Tags: google-plus

What's method of [this](http://socialstatistics.com/) site? How are their profile's ID, information retreived ?

Is there any Google API for google+ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how it started. I entered maybe 30 profiles. The rest was added manually by visitors...

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on an unofficial php api that can pull public profile and relationship data. You could probably use it to do something similar.

Here's the source on GitHub: https://github.com/jmstriegel/php.googleplusapi

Look in `tests/plususer.php` for an example of how to use it.

You can basically do something like this:

```
$followees = PlusPerson::FetchVisiblePlusPeople( $googleplus_id );
$followers = PlusPerson::FetchIncomingPlusPeople( $googleplus_id );
```

...which will give you an array of people a person has in their circles, and an array of people that have circled the person.

Answer (score 2):

The API has now been announced at: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/09/getting-started-on-google-api.html and the official homepage is: http://developers.google.com/+/

Answer (score 0):

Google says there is going to be an API *soon*. What I suspect they are doing is parsing the public profile page go get the stats.

Comment: but ID is random. How is that ID retreived?

Comment: Someone manually puts it into the site. The id is in the url of the profile page. there is a box on the right to do it called: `Track your Google+ statistics`

Comment: yes but I don't belive someone would add himself to an empty site (when it started)

Answer (score -1):

Got it. I'm taking Ids from search

First ten pages:
http://phpcode.eu/google/